# Remove thumbnails create from input js

Tags: javascript, image, input

That is my problem : 
I have written javascript code to create a thumbnail when a user uploads an image. I would now like to add a feature which allows a user to click on an "X" which will then deleted the image.

this is my code :

```js
 var imageLoader = document.getElementById('fUpload2');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas2');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


function handleImage(e){
 
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    document.getElementById("imageCanvas2").style.height =  canvas.height;
    document.getElementById("imageCanvas2").style.maxWidth = "200px";
    document.getElementById("imageCanvas2").style.maxHeight = "200px";
    document.getElementById("imageCanvas2").style.border = "1px solid #000";
    
  }
        img.src = event.target.result;
  var alte= canvas.height;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
}
```

```css
   .image-upload-gal > input {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
   <div class="well"> 
       <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/ServiceUpload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          
           <div class="form-group" style="padding:14px;">
                                  <div class="image-upload-gal" >
    <label for="fUpload2">
        Add foto
    </label>
   <input type="file" name="fUpload" id="fUpload2"  />
  <br>
  
   <canvas id="imageCanvas2" ></canvas>
 
         
</div>
           </div>
           <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" value="f_upload" name="up" style="margin-top: -20px;">Submit Photo</button>
           
       </form>
          </div>
```

and that is another code ( i need 2 code is long story :D )

```js
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
.thumb {
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  }

input{
  
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
      
                 
    <div class="image-upload" >
<label for="upload">
       Add foto
    </label>
<input type="file" id="upload" name="fUpload"  />
 <input type="hidden" name="up" value="f_upload" />
<output id="list"></output>
</div>
                        
         
         <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" value="newpost" name="NewPost" style="margin-top: -10px;">Submit</button>
         </form>
```

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve]. There is a lot of code here, and not enough text describing the problem you are having. See also [ask]. Note that SO is not code writing service; it is expected that you have tried something (at least some research, anyway) before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add an onclick event on a span containing a "x"

```
<span id="deleteImage">X</span>
```

Add the on Click handler then clear the canvas as you haven't saved the image anywhere else in that code

```
document.getElementById("deleteImage").onclick = function(){
    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Edited.
if you want to clear the canvas directly below is how.

```
canvas = document.getElementById("imageCanvas2");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: i tried but nothing...  its possible i wrong anything?

Comment: All you have to do is clear the canvas. Get the imageCanvas2 from the Dom and clear it using the method above I provided

Comment: can u explain me any code ? i tried to <script>your code</script> and html same but nothing

Comment: document.getElementById("imageCanvas2").clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

Comment: document.getElementById("deleteImage").onclick = function(){
    
document.getElementById("imageCanvas2").clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}   <-- not work     
google console : Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).clearRect is not a function

Comment: document.getElementById("deleteImage").onclick = function(){
canvas = document.getElementById("imageCanvas2");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
canvas.width = "0px";
var alte= "0px";
document.getElementById("imageCanvas2").style.border = "";
 document.getElementById("imageCanvas2").style.height ="0px";
}

that work

Comment: No because that was not the question you originally asked. You should do a little research, try your self and when you get stuck then create another post

Comment: and can u explain how remove second code thumbails ?